# What does ":&" mean in an Ansible/jinja2 YAML file?

Tags: ansible

What does ":&" mean in an Ansible/Jinja2 YAML file?

For example, in this line:

```
hosts: test-instances:&{{ target_host | default('None') }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an intersection of two hosts groups in Ansible (it is not a Jinja2 syntax and is not used except for the `hosts` declaration).

In your example, the play will run only on the host (or host group) specified in the `target_host` variable as long as it is listed in the `test-instances` inventory group.

If `target_host` is not specified or `target_host` is not listed in the `test-instances`, the play will be skipped (assuming there is no host named `None`).

Per [Working with Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html):

> You can also specify the intersection of two groups. This would mean the hosts must be in the group webservers and the host must also be in the group staging:
>
> ```
> webservers:&staging
> ```